# How to determine at what percentage an organ is functioning vs. what is expected?

Tags: diagnostics, icu-intensive-care-unit

Example:

1. Patient presents acute renal failure that has rapid progression.
2. Patient asks upon consultation “At what percent are my kidneys functioning to what they should be”. Physician responds with “about 12 percent”.

What mathematics would provide the requested information. Also, this is a general example as every situation is different. How would a physician provide a number such as this to a patient or colleague if approached with the question.

Comment: percentage of current function vs expected.

Comment: Could you edit my post to suite your suggestion? Your wording is superior to mine. Thank you for the contribution!

Comment: Cross-posted here: https://www.remindask.com/questions/603928/how-to-determine-at-what-percentage-an-organ-is-functioning

Answer (score -2, accepted):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=errjs0bN0_U

This is the answer to this question. I felt it necessary after so long to post something that explained this for everyone. Please watch, this video is great for med students and is more informative than any text anyone on here can provide.

Comment: Since links tend to die, it would help if you could summarize the video and what the answer to the question actually is.